# How to pass data from controller to view from post method with parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-5

I have a HttpGet method with a parameter. Then I submit a form from view and action is going to the same controller with HttpPost method. In post method, I do some controls and if they fail I want to return the same view with for example a ViewBag.
It's something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult someFunc(string s)
{
  ...
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult someFunc(int i, double d,string s)
{
  if(i < 0){
    //indicate that this is an error like ViewBag.error = "error"
    return View(s);
  }
  ...
}
```

In post method, I want to return the same view with indicating that there is an error. If get method was not using any parameter, it was working properly. I was doing that with a `ViewBag.error = smthng` but when parameters came, I couldn't figure it out. In view, in the same way I want to make that if my error type is not null show my error with an alert.
I tried `return Redirect(path?parameter=p)` but **ViewBag** did not worked with that way. Same thing happened with `return View(action,parameter)`. How can I make it?

Comment: Hi @aoiTenshi, From your description, it seems you do not know what is return view(). It just used to render a view, and it will not call any get method. `s` in your post action is a type of string, so when you return view with this string, it does not mean return `someFunc` view with `s` data, it means return view named `s` value. You should use `return View("someFunc",s)`. If this also does not work. please share your razor view. Besides, where did you add the ViewBag.error? It should be added in the post method.

Comment: Hi @Rena, yes I tried return View("someFunc",s) and this also does not work and I add ViewBag in post method. I want to then return the get function with that ViewBag added. I can add my razor page later. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @aoiTenshi, did you use any ajax to make form submit? And it seems you prefer to redirecting to get function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewBag.Error in the post method before returning the view, the view and method have same name :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult someFunc(int i, double d,string s)
{
   if(i < 0){
      ViewBag.Error = "Error" ;
      return View(s);
   }
}
```

Also, you can use Use RedirectToAction method if you want use the get method using TempData["param"] to pass the paramater in the method

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult someFunc(string s)
{
   ...
   ViewBag.Error = TempData["Error"];
   return View() ;
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult someFunc(int i, double d,string s)
{
   if(i < 0){
      //indicate that this is an error like ViewBag.error = "error"
      TempData["Error"] = "Error Something" ;
      string param = s ;
      return RedirectToAction("someFunc", new { s = param});
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, anything I send from post method did not reach to my view. TempData, ViewBag, ViewData none of them. As a solution I added a parameter "error" to my get method and send my error to my get method as a parameter. According to that I filled my ViewBag in my get method with that parameter.